# If else inside my echo inside <tr><td>

Tags: php, if-statement, html-table

How can I add if-else statement inside my echo tr and td?
I try this code below but my output is a blank page.

```
<?php
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("$query");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
$i="0";
$ext = EXT;
if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
    foreach($result as $value) {
        $i++;   
        $id = $value['id'];
        $gccode = $value['gccode'];
        $datecreated = $value['datecreated'];
        $notes= $value['notes'];
        $branch = $value['branch'];
        $groupid = $value['groupid'];
        $status = $value['status'];
        echo "<tr  class=\"gradeA\">
        <td>$i</td>
        <td>$id</td>
        <td>$gccode</td>
        <td>$datecreated</td>
        <td>$notes</td>
        <td>$branch</td>
        <td>" if ($value['groupid']=="1"){ echo  'Regular';}
        else { echo  'Complimentary'; } "</td>
        <td>$status</td>
        </tr>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't echo the `HTML`, close your `PHP` tags and output your `HTML`, then in your `td` open the `PHP` tags and do your logic. This will help with the readability a lot more.

Comment: Look into using MVC to separate your logic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to complete your `echo` statements properly:

```
echo "<tr  class=\"gradeA\">

  <td>$i</td>
  <td>$id</td>
  <td>$gccode</td>
  <td>$datecreated</td>
  <td>$notes</td>
  <td>$branch</td>
  <td>";
  if ($value['groupid']=="1"){ echo  'Regular';}
  else { echo  'Complimentary'; } 
  echo "</td>
      <td>$status</td>
  </tr>";
```

Again instead of writing if else statements, you can use a ternary operator.

So, your final optimized code should be:

```
echo "<tr  class=\"gradeA\">
      <td>$i</td>
      <td>$id</td>
      <td>$gccode</td>
      <td>$datecreated</td>
      <td>$notes</td>
      <td>$branch</td>
      <td>" . ($value['groupid']=="1") ? 'Regular' : 'Complimentary'. "</td><td>$status</td>
      </tr>";
```

Answer (score 4):

You can change this line like bellow:

```
<td>" . ($value['groupid']=="1" ? 'Regular' :  'Complimentary') . "</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to break the echo statement by semi colon (`;`)

Corrected code:

```
echo "<tr  class=\"gradeA\">
      <td>$i</td>
      <td>$id</td>
      <td>$gccode</td>
      <td>$datecreated</td>
      <td>$notes</td>
      <td>$branch</td>
      <td>";

if ($value['groupid']=="1"){
  echo 'Regular';
}
else {
  echo 'Complimentary';
}
echo "</td><td>$status</td></tr>";
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways of doing this.

One of them would be to *build* the HTML and store it in a variable, then use a full fledged `if else` to add to the variable e.g.

```
$myStr = '<tr class="gradeA">';
$myStr += '<td>' . $i . '</td>';
// snipped

if ($value['groupid'] == '1')
    $myStr += '<td>Regular</td>';
else
    $myStr += '<td>Complimentary</td>';

// do more string stuff

// return the built variable instead.
return $myStr;
```

But you can also use a ternary (shorthand if) statement. Using the same example:

```
$myStr = '<tr class="gradeA">';
$myStr += '<td>' . $i . '</td>';
// snipped

$myStr += '<td>' . ($value['groupid'] == '1' ? 'Regular' : 'Complimentary')  . '</td>';

// do more string stuff

// return the built variable instead.
return $myStr;
```

The main advantage to this method over straight out `echo` ing the content is that you can now also manipulate the variable itself in different places, in different ways - allowing for much more flexibility and more clean code (tho not always true).

Answer (score 1):

Your page is blank because of php error. You need to use semicolons after every php statement. replace your code with below one.

echo "

```
  <td>$i</td>
  <td>$id</td>
  <td>$gccode</td>
  <td>$datecreated</td>
  <td>$notes</td>
  <td>$branch</td>
  <td>";

   if ($value['groupid']=="1")
   { 
      echo  'Regular';
   }
   else 
   { 
      echo  'Complimentary';
   } 
   echo "</td>
      <td>$status</td>
  </tr>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Your page is blank because of php error. You need to use semicolons after every php statement.